# Salesforce API, extract lineage

Tags: rest, salesforce, metadata, data-lineage

I am trying to retrieve lineage information using salesforce different API.

I would like to find:

- links between tables and reports
- links between reports and dashboards

I have tried to explore the rest api, tooling api and metadata api but still did not find a way to do that.

Would anyone have an idea if that's possible or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Report-Dashboard should be easy, read up about querying [`DashboardComponent`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_dashboardcomponent.htm).

For report tables used it's messier. Some tracking could be done similar to how "Where is this used?" button works on custom fields (but won't help much for standard fields & objects!)

- you could download all report definitions to your VSCode project and experiment with some xml parsing.
- you could look into https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/320339/799 but looks like [it doesn't handle reports well if called normally](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm), you'd need to call it as bulk api (maybe experiment with Workbench)
- have a look at [`ReportType`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_reporttype.htm) metadata object. It'll only work for custom report types but looks promising? And reports can tell you which report type they use (if you've downloaded them to a project that is, I don't think it's queryable nicely but it's visible in metadata api's XML)